# Cobertura throws ClassNotFoundException in Android-project

Tags: android, unit-testing, cobertura

I have the following code snippet in one of my classes I'm unittesting:

```
AlgorithmParameterSpec parameterSpec;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        parameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(LOGON_KEY_ALIAS, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
                .setCertificateSubject(usernameToSubject(username))
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                .setCertificateNotBefore(start.getTime())
                .setCertificateNotAfter(end.getTime())
                .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .build();
    } else {
        parameterSpec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias(LOGON_KEY_ALIAS)
                .setSubject(usernameToSubject(username))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
                .build();
    }
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameterSpec);
```

The tests (for another method in the same class) run fine, however cobertura throws the following exception:

```
Unable to instrument file: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(CoberturaClassWriter.java:35)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.commons.LocalVariablesSorter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter$1.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:214)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:129)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:243)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:299)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:308)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.instrument(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:90)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.dsl.Cobertura.instrumentCode(Cobertura.java:74)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain.instrument(InstrumentMain.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:192)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaRunner.executeCobertura(CoberturaRunner.groovy:224)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaRunner.instrument(CoberturaRunner.groovy:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.InstrumentTask.instrument(InstrumentTask.groovy:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In my build.gradle I have:

```
 compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.new_frontiers.m2fa"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
```

Is there any possibility to tell cobertura where to look for the missing class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after all it was an issue with the [gradle-cobertura-plugin](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin). I added the dependency to the android.jar with `auxiliaryClasspath = project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath())` inside the cobertura-configuration of my build.gradle, but it was overridden by the plugin. After submitting a [patch](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/124)  it worked like a charm.

**UPDATE**

The new version 2.4.0 of the plugin contains the patch and works out of the box. A big thanks to Steven C. Saliman for acting so promptly.